# Creating an outer circle

Tags: human-resources

I work as a HR manager and it's been 5 months since I got on to this role.

My CEO asked me to come up with a plan to engage and build a community of people who will be interested to join our company in the future. I don't have previous experiences with the same.

I would like to get some suggestions and inputs on how can I build and form the community of people who got rejected from our interview process or people who can be our future employee to join our company?

Comment: What resources have you used for hiring / research new employees just now? Might those avenues not help with people who may join as well?

Comment: What industry are you in?

Comment: This heavily, heavily depends on what area you're in - there's no "one size fits all" here. If it's developers you're after, than hackathons could be a worthwhile avenue for instance, but that's unlikely to have an impact if you're after plumbers.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend any deals with universities. There is a lot of students who don't know how to start their career. They may be intrested in future working to your company. Maybe create a database of rejected people.

It also depends if you have any budget for this.
You can create advertisements and allow people to sign up via the form.